# Get a List using its ID

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to get a list using it's ID, however it's not working and I can't work out why

This works without a problem...

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example.org/sites/specific/staffhandbook"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Documents"];
        // process...
    }
```

So should this, but it doesn't?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example.org/sites/specific/staffhandbook"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["29540646-bcab-4beb-8a91-648c1f3178b8"];
        // process...
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `SPListCollection` accepts either an `Int32` (an index), a `String` (the name of the list), or a `Guid` (the identifier), so the above, you'd need to do:

```
Guid guid = new Guid("29540646-bcab-4beb-8a91-648c1f3178b8");
SPList list = web.Lists[guid];
```

Comment: doh! even when I was looking at an example I still didn't see it, thanks :-)